# Custom Loss Function with Spacy Textcat

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I've been looking around for a while now. I would like to know if it's possible to modify/customize the loss function of the spaCy [textcategorizer](https://spacy.io/api/textcategorizer).

I mean, when you want to distill a model (for instance BERT) and want to add a regression component in the loss function to optimize (regarding the probabilities of each class instead only the labels), I don't understand where I should look for. I tried to explore some [spaCy code](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/pipeline/pipes.pyx) but there is only a function to get the loss.

If someone know where to look for to visualize the loss function and change it (by writing a subclass for instance) it would be nice !

Thanks

Arnault

Answer (score 0):

SpaCy is ultimately built on top of [thinc](https://github.com/explosion/thinc) and therefore, if you want to do custom work, you should tinker with Thinc, not SpaCy. SpaCy typically allows you to initialize a pipe with a raw Thinc model.

Especially since SpaCy's philosophy is to provide one implementation that works well not necessarily a super customizable framework.

Comment: Hi thanks, for the reply, yes I saw on the explosion github the thinc repo, but same I couldn't find where they created the model for textcat with the loss function, so I would be able to write a subclass or something.

Do you have any idea where I can change that?

Comment: According to https://spacy.io/api/textcategorizer#init you can pass your model when you create the TextCategorizer object. I guess it would take some digging in the source code of Spacy to find the default model they use